# python json module import error

Tags: python, json

I am getting the following error while using python json module

```
# python
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Jan 11 2013, 02:09:42) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
ImportError: No module named json
>>>
```

can somebody help me on this?

Comment: you should upgrade your python 2.4 is quite old unless you need to maintain old stuff ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use simplejson  it will work

```
# python
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Jan 11 2013, 02:09:42) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import simplejson
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

To not worry about your Python version and (simple) portability:

```
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json
```

Comment: Can you explain what the above statements are doing as I am new to python

Answer (score 1):

as idjaw commented above.

You need to use:

```
import json
```

(Not jason)

---

Also, you need to use Python 2.6 or greater.

Comment: import json will not give you that error, as it is a valid module.

Comment: @ode2k it will if he is using an old python

Answer (score 1):

You are using Python 2.4.3 and [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) seems to be new in python 2.6, please update python.

Answer (score 0):

please use the stable python 2.7.x that would solve your issue and after that try using json

```
>>> import json
```

also you can use dir() command to check the methods and classes that comes with the `json` module in python programming, using the `dir()`

```
>>> dir(json)
['JSONDecoder', 'JSONEncoder', '__all__', '__author__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__', '_default_decoder', '_default_encoder', 'decoder', 'dump', 'dumps', 'encoder', 'load', 'loads', 'scanner']
```