# ImportError: No module named json when using Kalibr

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying Kalibr to calibrate my camera.

When I run this command: ./kalibr_calibrate_cameras --target dynamic/april_6x6.yaml --bag dynamic/dynamic.bag --modules pinhole-equi --topics /cam0/image_raw

I always get ImportError: No module named json. I am not very familiar with python. I am not sure where is wrong.

When I try

```
$ python
import json
```

It works well.
I also try to run the file that needs json here. Still, no issues found.

```
importing libraries
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/kalibr-build/devel/bin/kalibr_calibrate_imu_camera", line 5, in <module>
    exec(fh.read())
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/var/kalibr-build/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sm/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    exec(__fh.read())
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/var/kalibr-build/src/kalibr/Schweizer-Messer/sm_python/python/sm/plotCoordinateFrame.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pylab as p
  File "/home/ethan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "/home/ethan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 141, in <module>
    from ._version import get_versions
  File "/home/ethan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_version.py", line 7, in <module>
    import json
ImportError: No module named json
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 64, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
ImportError: No module named apport.fileutils

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/kalibr-build/devel/bin/kalibr_calibrate_imu_camera", line 5, in <module>
    exec(fh.read())
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/var/kalibr-build/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sm/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    exec(__fh.read())
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/var/kalibr-build/src/kalibr/Schweizer-Messer/sm_python/python/sm/plotCoordinateFrame.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pylab as p
  File "/home/ethan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "/home/ethan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 141, in <module>
    from ._version import get_versions
  File "/home/ethan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_version.py", line 7, in <module>
    import json
ImportError: No module named json
```

Comment: Please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/35942881/12870513

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work. I got  ImportError: No module named simplejson.

Comment: Try pip install simplejson

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably not that you are missing `json` which has been a standard library for a [long time (since 2.6, wow)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), but something else.

You at least appear to have a very old or unusual version of `matplotlib`; can you update it?

---

Perhaps your Python Path is wrong (could prevent some importing)

Further, perhaps you are missing something necessary to use [Apport](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport), which gives the error earlier

```
ImportError: No module named apport.fileutils
```

You may have some success installing `python-apport` (presumably you are using Ubuntu, so this would be [through `apt`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python-apport))