# Module Not Found Error: No module named 'json6'

Tags: python, module, pycharm, modulenotfounderror

I am getting this error after running my code in Pycharm. I checked everything but all is ok. what can I do of it?

> Module Not Found Error: No module named 'json6'

Comment: What is json6 ?

Comment: Can you post some code please. Presumably you are trying to import a module. Please show at least this section of the code.

Comment: From what I can tell, json6 is a superset of Javascript and therefore unrelated to Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No module named json in python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67715723/no-module-named-json-in-python3)